# How can i show satellite image as layer? in which format

Tags: openlayers-3

How can i show satellite image as layer? in which format should be this image?

Hi there!
I have satellite images like RapidEye.
I created local openstreetmap layer like [This example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/examples/localized-openstreetmap.html?q=local)
And now i want to add multiple layers like RGB, NDVI, NDWI. 
Give me tips pls,

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a wms server to publish your image as a layer. This can be done using geoserver or mapserver for example.
For the format of the image, depends on the wms server you are going to use. Geoserver accepts a large number of different formats details may be found [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.5/user/data/raster/index.html).

[Here](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.5/user/data/raster/worldimage.html) is also a description on how to publish a georefernced image on geoserver.

For other wms servers I am not so familiar. But more or less the process should be the same.